# Tabbed Contents for Googlebot

Tags: tabs, googlebot, tabbed

I have checked a lot of forum questions on how to tell Googlebot to crawl my tabbed contents, but of no luck.

I need someone to punch my face and say that Googlebot will never prioritise tabbed contents.

Or, are there other ways that you might know of that will tell Googlebot to crawl our tabbed contents as well? E.g. disable javascript for Googlebot.

Thanks.